# clearInterval not working, Interval Undefined

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

Okay, so I've read like 20 other questions asked here and elsewhere on the web concerning a similar thing, but it all ended up being that they didn't like, set a variable properly and assumed the clearInterval was based on a function ID or some such thing.
Here's what I've got (there's more, but it's rather lengthy and from I understand this is the important bit):

```
var fan1 = function () {
    var f1 = setInterval("flare1baserotate()",10);
    setTimeout("clearInterval(f1)",2000);
};
```

Basically, the "fan1()" function gets called properly, the setInterval runs properly, as the "flare1baserotate()" function properly runs and rotates my object every 10 milliseconds, but the problem comes in where "clearInterval(f1)" doesn't run properly after 20 seconds as I feel it should. 
What do I have to do to get it to clear after 20 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a string with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, the code in it will be run in global `window` scope, rather than the scope from where its called. The `f1` declared inside the function `fan1` is thus not available from the line `clearInterval(f1)` which gets executed in global `window` scope. One easy solution would be to make `f1` global.

```
var f1;
var flare1baserotate = function(){console.log("hi");};
var fan1 = function () {
    f1 = setInterval("flare1baserotate()",10);
    setTimeout("clearInterval(f1)",2000);
};
```

And the recommended practice is to use closures rather than passing lines of code as strings.

And a hard way without globals might look like

```
var flare1baserotate = function() {
    console.log("hi");
};
var fan1 = function() {
    var f1 = setInterval("flare1baserotate()", 10);
    setTimeout((function(f1) {
        return function() {
            clearInterval(f1);
        }
    })(f1), 2000);
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I like your answer more because it actually explains why my way didn't work and this way does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I believe all functions passed to `setTimeout` will be executed in `window` scope. Only if we exclusively bind it to some scope using `bind` or by returning a `function` from anonymous function to exclusively change the scope then only the scope changes, and this includes named functions and anonymous functions passed to `setTimeout`. Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: @sabithpocker: Depends on what you mean by "scope," because a lot of people misuse the word. In JavaScript, the scope of a function is defined entirely by where the function is created. So if you pass an actual *function* into `setTimeout`, it runs in the scope it was created in. Example: http://jsbin.com/hatexu/1/edit Sometimes people use "scope" incorrectly to refer to the value of `this` within the function. All functions called via `setTimeout` are called with `this` referring to the global object (the window, on browsers).

Answer (score 1):

use this instead:

```
var f1 = setInterval(function() {flare1baserotate();},10);
setTimeout(function() {clearInterval(f1); },2000);
```